# How to delete a row, if condition on a date is met, through script (half solved)

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, datetime-format

I have soma data, starting from  `A10` to column `M`, until the 59th row.

I have some dates in column `F10:F` that are text strings, converted to official dates in column `N` ([here the question with the process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74828017/convert-a-string-to-a-date-format-using-a-script-or-a-google-sheets-built-in-for))

`M3` is set to `=NOW()`.

In cell `N3` I have: `=M3+14`.

I want to delete all the rows, with a date in column `N10:N` that comes before [today + 2 weeks] (so cell `N3`).

When I create a script in Apps Script, it doesn't run the `if statement`, but if I leave it in comments,  it can go in the `for loop` and deletes the rows, so I'm pretty sure the problem is, again, date formatting.

In this question I ask: how do I compare the values of `N10:N` with `N3`, in order to delete all the rows that don't meet the condition `if(datesNcol <= targetDate)`?  (in code is written as `if (rowData[i] < flatArray)`)

I leave also a demo sheet with this problem explained in detail and two alternatives (getBackground condition and numeric days condition).

**Attempts:**
This is a simplified code example:

```
const gen = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Generatore');
const bVals = gen.getRange('B10:B').getValues();
const bFilt = bVals.filter(String);
const dataLastRow = bFilt.length;

function deleteExpired() {
  dateCorrette(); //ignore, formula that puts corrected dates from N10 to dataLastRow

  var dateCorrect = gen.getRange(10,14,dataLastRow,1).getValues();
  var targetDate = gen.getRange('N3').getValues();
  var flatArray = [].concat.apply([], targetDate);
      
  for (var i = dateCorrect.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    var rowData = dateCorrect[i];

    if (rowData[i] < flatArray) {
      gen.deleteRow(i+10);
    }
  }
};
```

If run the script, nothing is deleted.
If I //comment the if function and the closing bracket, it delets all the rows of the list one by one.
I can't manage to meet that condition.

Right now, it logs this `[Sun Jan 01 10:33:20 GMT-05:00 2023]` as `flatArray`
and this `[Wed Dec 21 03:00:00 GMT-05:00 2022]` as `dateCorrect[49]`, so the first row to delete, that is the 50th (is correct for all the dateCorrect[i] dates).

I tried putting a `getTime()` method in the `targetDate`  variable, but it only functions if there is the `getValue()` method, not `getValues()`, so I then don't know how to use `getTime()` method on `rowData`, which is based on `dateCorrected[i]`, which have to use the `getValues()` method. And then it also doesn't accept the `flatArray` variable, that has to be commented out (or it logs `[ ]` for `flatArray`, not the corrected date)

I leave the other attempts in the demo sheet, because I want to prioritize this problem around the date and make it clear in my head.

Thanks for all the help.

[DEMO SHEET, ITA Locale time](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VlmHl2idplGVRMuGMPA42U9uRsYDUjFdHhBxLs8G0zc/edit#gid=0)

I don't know how the demo sheet works with Apps Script, I suggest to copy the code in a personal sheet

**UPDATE:**

I've also tried putting an extra column, with an `IF` built-in function that writes "del" if the function has to be deleted.

```
=IF(O10>14;"del";"")
```

And then

```
var boba = gen.getRange(10,16,bLast,1).getDisplayValues();
.
.
if (boba[i] == 'del')
```

This does the job. But I can't understand why the other methods don't work.

Comment: ```rowData[i]``` inside your for loop is equal to ```dateCorrect[i][i]```, but ```dateCorrect``` itself is values in 2D array format contains only 1 column in each row according to ```gen.getRange(10,14,dataLastRow,1).getValues();```, which means... ```if (rowData[i] < flatArray)``` seem to be always testing ```if (undefined < flatArray)``` which... I think it will never be ```true```.

Comment: Thank you, I've put an [i] and it fact it logs null type. But from this infromation I can't go any further. I've tried another solution that I'm writing inside the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  It seems like you do a lot of things that aren't necessary.  Unless I'm missing something.

A few notes.  I typically do not use global variable, unless absolutely necessary.  I don't create a variable for last row unless I have to use that value multiple times in my script. I use the method `Sheet.getLastRow()`.  `dataCorrect` is a 2D array of 1 column so the second index can only be `[0]`.  And `getRange('N4')` is a single cell so `getValue()` is good enough.

```
function deleteExpired() {
  const gen = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Generatore');
  var dateCorrect = gen.getRange(10,14,gen.getLastRow()-9,1).getValues();
  var targetDate = gen.getRange('N3').getValue();
      
  for (var i = dateCorrect.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (dataCorrect[i][0] < targetDate) {
      gen.deleteRow(i+10);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function delRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const gsh = ss.getSheetByName('Generatore');
  const colB = gsh.getRange('B10:B' + gsh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var colN = gsh.getRange('N10:N' + gsh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var tdv = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate() + 14).valueOf();//current date + 14
  let d = 0;
  colN.forEach((n, i) => {
    if (new Date(n).valueOf() < tdv) {
      gsh.deleteRow(i + 10 - d++);
    }
  });
}
```